# Select change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

First of all, I did research on web about my problem but could not find any solution, and that made me to ask the question once again.

I have a select which is registered with `change` event , so when i change it on browser event fires but when i try pro-grammatically it does not work.

Select:

```
<select name="symbol" id="symbol" class='input-xmini'>
    <option>-Choose Symbol-</option>
    <option value="Categories">Categories</option>
    <option value="UpcInfo">UPC</option>
    <option value="Transaction">Transaction</option>
    <option value="Ticket">Ticket</option>
</select>
```

Event Registration:

```
$('#symbol').on('change',function(){    
    alert('changing symbol')
});
```

What i tried already:

1. `$('#symbol').val('Categories').trigger('change')`
2. `$('#symbol').val('Categories').change()`
3. registered event handler inside document.ready function and also inside script tag itself.
4. `$(document).on('change','#symbol',function(){}`

I need to change it pro-grammatically but this is not working.

Please people dont think i am just another noob who is asking question already asked multiple times.Help. Thanks.

**NOTE:** I have tried almost everything but it does not work , can someone tell me theoretically why this would not work?

Comment: which browser ? which jq ver

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/UY2wQ/ on google chrome

Comment: Version jquery 1.8, browser chrome on linux

Comment: Which other `js` are you using on the same page?

Comment: @Anup some Timepicker.js plugin of jquery i guess

Answer (score 2):

I did this over on the function

```
$("body").on("change","#symbol",function(){
   alert('changing symbol')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pTq2X/

Comment: Why would this fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your Js may be conflicting, so try this :-

```
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(function(){
       jq('#symbol').on('change',function(){    
       alert('changing symbol');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could've been the problem, but then the event `on('change',function(){..}` wouldn't have worked